# Web Services Math

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I need to compute monthly payment (M) for an installment loan given the loan amount (P), period (in years), and the annual percentage rate.  M = (P * i * (1 + i)n) / ((1 + i)n - 1) where i = annual percentage rate / 1200 and n = period * 12.

I need to do this using a web service on visual studio. I can't seem to use the Math.Pow in a web service.  this is my Code in the method:

This is my error message: Error  1  'ProjectFive.payment.Math(double, double, double, double)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context   c:\users\parodeghero\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ProjectFive\ProjectFive\payment.asmx.cs  27  38  ProjectFive

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace ProjectFive
{
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

public class payment : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public double Math(double loan, double rate, double period, double payment)
    {

        rate = rate / 100;
        period = period * 12;

      payment = loan*(rate/1200)*Math.Pow((1+(rate/1200)), period)/ Math.Pow((1 + (rate/1200)), period) - 1;
      return payment;         
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what "I can't seem to use" exactly mean ? you get compiler error or what ?

Comment: Shouldn't the denominator be `Math.Pow((1 + (rate / 1200)), period - 1)`?

Comment: public double Math(double loan, double rate, double period, double payment)
        {
yes, it says this code above isn't valid

Comment: Please post the full method definition (and the class definition).

Comment: I'd try breaking each section of that calculation into its own variable. Then use those separate variables in the final calculation. That might help pinpoint the problem. And it may make the code easier to read and maintain anyway.

Comment: @asgurl: "It says this code above isn't valid."  What says this?  _Specifically_ what does it say?  If there's an error message, include it in the question.  Specify what line of code creates the error message.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This is a sincere question with a specific problem. Yes, it would have been better if the exact problem was specified at first, but sometimes people need to be helped toward forming good questions. Harsh crowd...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rename your method, you can't call it Math !

Comment: @Mitch: I think that's the actual answer though. asgurl can't use Math.Pow() because that's also the name of her method.